# A alguien le funciona el InAppUpdate v1.8.1 de Google Play para Unity?

Tags: unity, unity3d, unity2d, google-play

Hasta la versión 1.7 del InAppUpdate de Google Play para Unity no tenia problema de funcionamiento. Actualice a la versión 1.8.1 y me ha dejado de funcionar, y he visto que a varios le sucedió lo mismo.
Probé también un Asset que hay en la Asset Store de Unity y solo funciona con la versión 1.7 y al hablar con el creador me comento que con la versión 1.8.1 tiene problemas. Es como que han modificado algo en el código que en la guía oficial no han actualizado.
Alguien que lo este usando sin problemas y quiera compartir el código de como lo esta implementando seria de gran ayuda. Muchas Gracias

Este es el código que yo utilizo y ya no me funciona:

```
using System.Collections;
using Google.Play.AppUpdate;
using Google.Play.Common;
using UnityEngine;

namespace _Scripts
{
    public class InAppUpdate : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private AppUpdateManager _appUpdateManager;
        private AppUpdateOptions _appUpdateOptions;
        private AppUpdateInfo _appUpdateInfoResult;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _appUpdateManager = new AppUpdateManager();
            _appUpdateOptions = AppUpdateOptions.ImmediateAppUpdateOptions();
            StartCoroutine(CheckForUpdate());
        }

        IEnumerator CheckForUpdate()
        {
            PlayAsyncOperation<AppUpdateInfo, AppUpdateErrorCode> appUpdateInfoOperation =
                _appUpdateManager.GetAppUpdateInfo();
            yield return appUpdateInfoOperation;

            if (appUpdateInfoOperation.IsSuccessful)
            {
                _appUpdateInfoResult = appUpdateInfoOperation.GetResult();
                if (_appUpdateInfoResult.UpdateAvailability.Equals(UpdateAvailability.UpdateAvailable)) StartCoroutine(StartImmediateUpdate());
                
            }
            else Debug.LogError("Error checking for app update: " + appUpdateInfoOperation.Error);
            
        }
        IEnumerator StartImmediateUpdate()
        {
            var startUpdateRequest = _appUpdateManager.StartUpdate(
                _appUpdateInfoResult,
                _appUpdateOptions);
            yield return startUpdateRequest;

            if (startUpdateRequest.IsDone){}
                else Debug.LogError("Error starting app update: " + startUpdateRequest.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el error en la consola de Unity:

Exception: Field currentActivity or type signature  not found
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr javaClass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[FieldType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._GetStatic[FieldType] (System.String fieldName) (at :0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.GetStatic[FieldType] (System.String fieldName) (at :0)
Google.Play.Common.UnityPlayerHelper.GetCurrentActivity () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.common/Runtime/Scripts/UnityPlayerHelper.cs:32)
Google.Play.AppUpdate.Internal.AppUpdateManagerPlayCore..ctor () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.appupdate/Runtime/Scripts/Internal/AppUpdateManagerPlayCore.cs:34)
Google.Play.AppUpdate.Internal.AppUpdateManagerInternal..ctor () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.appupdate/Runtime/Scripts/Internal/AppUpdateManagerInternal.cs:35)
Google.Play.AppUpdate.AppUpdateManager..ctor () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.appupdate/Runtime/Scripts/AppUpdateManager.cs:33)
_Scripts.InAppUpdate.Awake () (at Assets/_Scripts/InAppUpdate.cs:16)

Comment: ¿Cómo que no funciona? ¿Obtienes algún error o algo? Si es así, edita la pregunta mencionandolo.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Ya actualicé la pregunta. Tu estas utilizando la versión 1.8.1? Te funciona?

Comment: No, no lo uso pero tal vez pueda dar una mano. Esperaba que el error de información sobre cómo resolverlo. Probaste el código de Android? https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/unity?hl=es-419

Comment: Gracias por responder nuevamente. Si lo he probado y tampoco funciona con la última versión 1.8.1. Y si con la 1.7. Parece que tendré que volver a esa versión. Pero mi duda era si a alguien le funcionaba está última.